# What icon can i use to reperesent twins

Tags: logo, symbols

Im designing a logo and need some symbols to represent twins or 2. Thank you

Comment: Hi Target, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. As-is, your question is basically a brainstorming question or a request for free work, and those are off topic here. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3):

There is an actual symbol for *twins* (gemini) it looks like this[image]

alternatively i'd use something like this:[image]